# Not able to save data using Blazor client template and ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: blazor

I have created a Blazor client app as frond end and ASP.NET Core Web API to serve data, but I am not able to save data using the Blazor client template. Blazor client app is not able to call the API.

However, I can save data if I use the Blazor core hosted template.

This is the code:

```
// Blazor Client APP
@page "/register"
@inject HttpClient Http

@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IUriHelper UriHelper

<h1>Create</h1>
<h3>Employee</h3>
<hr />
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name : @emp.Name</label>
                    <input for="Name" class="form-control" @bind="@emp.Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Gender" class="control-label">Gender</label>
                    <select asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" @bind="@emp.Gender">
                        <option value="">-- Select Gender --</option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Department" class="control-label">Department</label>
                    <input asp-for="Department" class="form-control" @bind="@emp.Department" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="City" class="control-label">City</label>
                    <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" @bind="@emp.City" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @* <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @onclick="@CreateEmployee">Save</button>*@


                    @*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @onclick="@CreateEmployee">Create EMp</button>*@

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @onclick="@(async () => await CreateEmployee())">Save</button>

                    @*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @onclick="@CreateE">E Save</button>*@
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

@code {
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        protected async Task CreateEmployee()
        {
            await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:44364/api/User/emp", emp);
            UriHelper.NavigateTo("/register");
        }

        void cancel()
        {
            UriHelper.NavigateTo("/fetchemployee");
        }
}  

// ASP.NET Core Web API code
[HttpPost]
[Route("emp")]
public void Create(Employee emp)
{

}
```

Comment: "Blazor client app is not able to call the API." - error messages, details and code please.

Comment: Side note, you are using async the wrong way. That could be the cause here.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like an issue of CORS. Please check the console in the chrome dev tools after running the application. You might get `Failed to load <web API> : No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource` error.
The cause of this error is that the client and the server of the application are not on the same port. The browser will restrict the application to make web API calls due to same-origin policy.

To resolve this issue you need to enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in your application. Please refer to Microsoft documents at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0 for details.